# Analyzing the relationship between a series and a "subseries"

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression, granger-causality

There are two variables, $A$ and $B$. One of those variables consists of two "subseries" of data, $A_1$ and $A_2$.

There are time series data for $A_1$, $A_2$ and $B$. However, there is no data for $A$, only for the two different classes of which it consists of.

The series for $A_1$ and $A_2$ are very similar and highly correlated (albeit not cointegrated).

**My question:**

When I want to test whether $A_1$ can help in predicting $B$ (e.g. by testing whether the coefficients on the lags of $A_1$ are zero) in a time series framework, do I have to include all three series when estimating a (VAR-)model or can I apply pairwise tests (i.e. estimate a model for $A_1$ and $B$ and then, after finishing this task, another one for $A_2$ and $B$)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you have time series $A_1$, $A_2$ and $B$ and are interested in whether $A_1$ can help predict $B$ beyond the history of $B$ itself, then you would build a VAR model just for $A_1$ and $B$ to test that.

If you built a VAR model for $A_1$, $A_2$ and $B$ instead, you could only test whether $A_1$ can help predict $B$ beyond the own history of $B$ *and* the history of $A_2$ (unless you restrict the coefficients on the lagged values of $A_2$ to be zero in both the null and the alternative model in the likelihood ratio test; but that would effectively mean working within the bivariate model for $A_1$ and $B$ instead of the trivariate model for $A_1$, $A_2$ and $B$).

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. I struggled with the three variable case because I could not distinguish what condition I am actually testing when using tests on a VAR with all variables and with just two of them, but I see it now. Thank you!

Comment: @Kuma, I am happy I could help. I had not encoutered such a question before, so I had to think on the spot, but I hope my reasoning is fine.

Comment: Me neither, that is why I wondered whether someone can help me with this issue. I am grateful that you took your time to answer it, and I think your reasoning is perfectly fine.